# Using Pandoc with Swift

Tags: swift, pandoc

I'm trying to use Pandoc to convert LaTeX to Markdown.  I need to create a file and then run the pandoc terminal command.  The problem is the file I create isn't in the same directory that I'm running the terminal commands in.

I tried using shell("cd") but it doesn't move you to the user's folder.

Any ideas?

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    func shell(args: String...) -> Int32 {
        let task = NSTask()
        task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
        task.arguments = args
        task.launch()
        task.waitUntilExit()
        return task.terminationStatus
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        shell("pwd")

        let file = "input.txt"
        let text = "\\emph{test}"

        if let dir : NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first {
            let inputPath = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file)

            //writing
            do {
                try text.writeToFile(inputPath, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                shell("pandoc","-f","latex","-t","markdown","input.txt","-o","output.txt")
            }
            catch {/* error handling here */}

            let outputPath = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("output.txt")
            //reading
            do {
                let inputText = try NSString(contentsOfFile: inputPath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print(inputText)

                let convertedText = try NSString(contentsOfFile: outputPath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print(convertedText)

            }
            catch {/* error handling here */}
        }


    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```

Here is the output

```
/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FlashCardPreview-gqzwutewnxspazcdloxqruaikvel/Build/Products/Debug
env: pandoc: No such file or directory
\emph{test}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is partly because the task's executable is set to `env` which itself executes `pandoc`; but in the meantime it loses the working directory.

The solution to this is to set `launchPath` to the Pandoc executable.

This is also because we have to use `inputPath` and `outputPath` in the task arguments instead of just the filenames, *or* to set a `currentDirectoryPath` for the task.

Working version 1:

```
func shell(args: String...) -> Int32 {
    let task = NSTask()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/local/bin/pandoc"
    task.arguments = args
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return task.terminationStatus
}
```

and

```
let file = "input.txt"
let text = "\\emph{test}"

if let dir : NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first {

    let inputPath = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file)
    let outputPath = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("output.txt")

    //writing
    do {
        try text.writeToFile(inputPath, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        shell("-f","latex","-t","markdown", inputPath, "-o", outputPath)
    }
    catch { print(error) }

    //reading
    do {
        let inputText = try NSString(contentsOfFile: inputPath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(inputText)

        let convertedText = try NSString(contentsOfFile: outputPath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(convertedText)

    }
    catch { print(error) }
}
```

Working version 2:

```
func shell(args: String...) -> Int32 {
    let task = NSTask()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/local/bin/pandoc"
    if let dir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first {
        task.currentDirectoryPath = dir
    }
    task.arguments = args
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return task.terminationStatus
}
```

and

```
let file = "input.txt"
let text = "\\emph{test}"

if let dir : NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first {

    let inputPath = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file)
    let outputPath = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("output.txt")

    //writing
    do {
        try text.writeToFile(inputPath, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        shell("-f","latex","-t","markdown","input.txt","-o","output.txt")
    }
    catch { print(error) }


    //reading
    do {
        let inputText = try NSString(contentsOfFile: inputPath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(inputText)

        let convertedText = try NSString(contentsOfFile: outputPath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(convertedText)

    }
    catch { print(error) }
}
```

Prints:

> \emph{test}
>   *test*