# python module not found when launched from Swift

Tags: python, swift, cairo

I created a `svg2png.command` file that simply launches a python file. It calls the python file this way:

```
shell1 = './scripts/cairosvg.py ../projects/%s/wip/skin/%s/screenLayout/staticScreens/%s -o ../projects/%s/wip/skin/%s/screenLayout/staticScreens/%s' % (projectName, projectName, filename, projectName, projectName, filename[:-4]+".png")
os.system(shell1)
```

The python file `cairosvg.py` imports a module (cairo). It looks like:

```
import cairosvg
cairosvg.main()
```

When I double-click on the `svg2png.command` file, everything goes as expected, and a png file is created out of an svg file. Good.

Then I tried to launch the command from an OSX Swift app:

```
let task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "svg2png.command"
task.arguments = ""
task.launch()
task.waitUntilExit()
```

I have done this several times with simpler python scripts and they all worked as expected. However in that case, I get the error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):", "  File \"scripts/svg2png.py\", line 4, in <module>", "    import cairo", "ImportError: No module named cairo", "s"
```

How come this cairo module can be found when double-clicking on the .command, but not when launched from Swift? Also, a way to fix this would be great.

The environment variables, when working:

```
{'LC_CTYPE': 'UTF-8', 'TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION': '343.7', 'LOGNAME': 'username', 'USER': 'username', 'HOME': '/Users/username', 'PATH': '/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/minicom/2.2/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin/jamf', 'DISPLAY': '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.9lqHCFuqkq/org.macosforge.xquartz:0', 'TERM_PROGRAM': 'Apple_Terminal', 'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'TERM': 'xterm-256color', 'Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render': '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.3vWnYf4EMF/Render', 'SHLVL': '2', 'XPC_FLAGS': '0x0', '_': '/usr/local/bin/python', 'TERM_SESSION_ID': '24056B9D-EAD4-4A77-A38A-A98909725024', 'XPC_SERVICE_NAME': '0', 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK': '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.67dyQjSHcg/Listeners', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'LC_ALL': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'TMPDIR': '/var/folders/4c/0qxnphys699fxty03712k30h0000gn/T/', 'OLDPWD': '/Users/username', '__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING': '0x1F5:0x0:0x0', 'PWD': '/Users/username/Documents/GIT/studio_design_delivery/UnifyStudioProcess/tools'}
```

When not working:

```
{'_': '/usr/bin/python', 'LOGNAME': 'username', 'USER': 'username', 'XPC_SERVICE_NAME': '0', 'HOME': '/Users/username', 'PATH': '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin', 'DISPLAY': '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.9lqHCFuqkq/org.macosforge.xquartz:0', 'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'SHLVL': '1', 'XPC_FLAGS': '0x0', '__XCODE_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR_PATHS': '/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/USPReleaser-dhgtnfxnfhrtuzcwyapzztrkzifr/Build/Products/Debug', 'MallocNanoZone': '1', 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK': '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.67dyQjSHcg/Listeners', 'DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH': '/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/USPReleaser-dhgtnfxnfhrtuzcwyapzztrkzifr/Build/Products/Debug', 'NSUnbufferedIO': 'YES', 'DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/USPReleaser-dhgtnfxnfhrtuzcwyapzztrkzifr/Build/Products/Debug:/usr/lib/system/introspection', 'Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render': '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.3vWnYf4EMF/Render', 'LC_ALL': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'TMPDIR': '/var/folders/4c/0qxnphys699fxty03712k30h0000gn/T/', 'OLDPWD': '/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/USPReleaser-dhgtnfxnfhrtuzcwyapzztrkzifr/Build/Products/Debug', '__XPC_DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH': '/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/USPReleaser-dhgtnfxnfhrtuzcwyapzztrkzifr/Build/Products/Debug', '__XPC_DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/USPReleaser-dhgtnfxnfhrtuzcwyapzztrkzifr/Build/Products/Debug', '__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING': '0x1F5:0x0:0x0', 'PWD': '/Users/username/Documents/GIT/studio_design_delivery/UnifyStudioProcess/tools'}
```

They're definitely different, any idea?

Comment: Have your script print the environment variables when you launch it. There could be a difference there that explains why it doesn't work from Swift. For instance, nothing in your .bashrc or .profile will be evaluated when you start your Swift program.

Comment: environment variables added in both cases

Comment: `I tried to launch the command from an OSX Swift app` How? Show how you do it, please.

Comment: Via an NSTask, I added the code in the original post.

Comment: It *may* be an issue of "current directory", see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34910691/2227743

Comment: Thanks for the input Eric. I tried to use your link but could not quite apply this to my situation... could you elaborate on how I can use this?

Comment: `task.launchPath` is already set in my case, to where the `.command` file dwells.